# Using SOQL, how can I tell which Users are currently locked out?

Tags: soql, login, forgot-your-password

The title basically asks the question - using SOQL, how can I tell which of my Users are current locked out because they forgot or fat-fingered their password too many times?

Using this basic information, I would like to someday be able to either:

1. Proactively reach out to a user who is in this situation OR
2. Identify a potential security threat before the password cooling-off period expires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the relatively new UserLogin sobject to get this,

```
select id, username from user where id in (select userId from userLogin where isPasswordLocked=true)
```